# Does Python's heapify() not play well with list comprehension and slicing?

Tags: python, heap, list-comprehension

I found an interesting bug in a program that I implemented somewhat lazily, and wondered if I'm comprehending it correctly. The short version is that [Python's `heapq` implementation](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) doesn't actually order a list, it merely groks the list in a heap-centric way. Specifically, I was expecting `heapify()` to result in an ordered list that facilitated list comprehension in an ordered fashion.

Using a priority cue example, as in the Python documentation:

```
from heapq import heapify, heappush, heappop
from random import shuffle

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

lst = []

# iterate over a pseudo-random list of unique numbers
for i in sample(range(100), 15):
    it = Item("Some name for %i" % i)
    heappush(lst, (i, it))

print([i[0] for i in lst])
```

Results in

```
>>> [2, 22, 7, 69, 32, 40, 10, 97, 89, 33, 45, 51, 94, 27, 67]
```

This, we note, is not the *original* ordering of the list, but apparently some heap-centric ordering as [described here](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#theory). I was lazily expecting this to be fully ordered.

As a test, running the list through heapify() results in no change (as the list is already heap-ishly ordered):

```
heapify(lst)

print([i[0] for i in lst])

>>> [2, 22, 7, 69, 32, 40, 10, 97, 89, 33, 45, 51, 94, 27, 67]
```

Whereas iterating through the list with the `heappop()` function results in ordering as expected:

```
lst2 = []
while lst: lst2.append(heappop(lst))

print([i[0] for i in lst2])

>>> [2, 7, 10, 22, 27, 32, 33, 40, 45, 51, 67, 69, 89, 94, 97]
```

So, it would seem that `heapq` does not order a list (at least in the human sense of the word), but rather the `heappush()` and `heappop()` functions are able to grok the heap-ishly ordered list.

**The result: Any slicing and list comprehension operations on a heapified list will yield non-ordered results.**

Is this true, and is this *always* true?

(BTW: Python 3.0.1 on a WinXP system)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A heap is not a sorted list (it's a representation of a partially sorted binary tree).

So yes, you're right, if you expect a heapified list to behave like a sorted list, you'll be disappointed.  The only sorting assumption you can make about a heap is that `heap[0]` is always its smallest element.

(It's difficult to add much to what you've already written - your question is an excellent writeup of How Things Are.  8-)

Comment: Yeah, I mostly posted it so that it would be available if someone else had the same problem, but it's good to know that I misunderstood those docs and should have read them more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

> The result: Any slicing and list
>   comprehension operations on a
>   heapified list will yield non-ordered
>   results.
>
> Is this true, and is this always true?

If you just want to get a one-time sorted list, use:

```
myList.sort()
```

Priority queues/heaps can be used to implement a sort, or they can be used to keep a queue in priority form.  Insertions into  a heap are O(lg n), gets are O(1), and removals are O(lg n), which is a lot better than just resorting the entire list over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

"""I was expecting heapify() to result in an ordered list that facilitated list comprehension in an ordered fashion.""": If this expectation was based on a reading of the manual, you should raise a docs bug report.

""" The result: Any slicing and list comprehension operations on a heapified list will yield non-ordered results. Is this true, and is this always true?""": Just like e.g. random.shuffle(), the mentioned activity is not defined to produce "ordered" results. It **may** produce "ordered" results occasionally, but this is coincidental and not to be relied on and not worth asking (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

" The result: Any slicing and list comprehension operations on a heapified list will yield non-ordered results. Is this true, and is this always true?" No, it is not always true. Although it will be non-ordered most of the time, it is possible for it to be ordered. heapify() produces a list that satisfies the "heap invariant". In this case, it is a min-heap. It turns out that a sorted list also satisfies the heap invariant (see [heapq](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) paragraph 4: "heap.sort() maintains the heap invariant"). So in theory it is possible that a heapified list will also happen to be sorted.